# The choice of abbreviation "TF" and "TN" in EGA II

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

I am a native French speaker, yet I cannot guess what the abbreviations "TF" and "TN" stand for in page 39 (where they define them). I assume that the F stands for some kind of Finite and N for some kind of Nul, but I can't figure out the T. Does anyone know? That would be a really fun fact to know.

Comment: My guess : (TF) = Type fini, (TN) = Type nul (I am really not sure, specially for the second one)

Comment: That would make sense, but so many things are of type fini in algebraic geometry, so I don't see why they made an abbreviation for this one... But nice guess!